# Hurricane Shutters

Tags: windows, shutters, hurricane-panels, florida

This porch with windows almost to the ceiling was an addition to the house. The wood at the top is not drilled into anything. It is just sitting against the windows. Is it possible to install hurricane shutters on these windows with this design?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please ask the question about water stains  separately ... this site is not a chat forum